# Link facebook application request to facebook application page. Considered invalid because it is a Facebook url

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas, facebook-app-requests

I can successfully send app requests by using `method: 'apprequests'` and the receiver gets the notification properly. I know the page to be shown when the user clicks on the request is the one you put as Canvas URL/Secure Canvas URL.

The thing is I had already set up an App Page for my app, so it makes a lot of sense to lead the user to this page when he/she accepts the request. But I cannot put my app url as Canvas URL because Facebook will not allow it (*error: is invalid because it is a Facebook url*).

In similar questions, many suggest a redirection but I wonder if there is a more direct/proper way.

Comment: Redirecting from canvas to anywhere else is not allowed either. App requests are _supposed_ to be handled on canvas – because the assumption is that the invited user can start playing your game right there. If that is not the case – then you should not be using requests in the first place.

Comment: Well, 'apprequests' works just fine in a mobile. When you click in the invitation, you go to Google Play/App Store, so I thought this would be valid for browser too.